# 'error': 'invalid_request', 'error_description': 'Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing'

Tags: django, python-3.x, oauth-2.0

I am trying to get **access_token** after getting **code** from my api provider.

Here is my function;

```
def get_token():
    params = {
        'grant_type' : GRANT_TYPE,
        'client_id' : CLIENT_ID,
        'client_secret' : CLIENT_SECRET,
        'code' : CODE,
        'redirect_uri' : REDIRECT_URI
    }

    HEADERS = {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }

    req = requests.post(ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, params=params, headers=HEADERS)

    result = req.json()
    print (result) # in order to see it on the console.

    return result
```

However I am getting this error;

```
{'error': 'invalid_request', 'error_description': 'Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing'}
```

What could I do wrong here?

**EDIT (added the related part from the provider's documentation):**

the related part from the doc (because the document is not in English, I tried to translate it as much as I can):

> Token Access
>   Example query
>
> ```
> POST http://www.MYPROVIDER.com/oauth/v2/token
>
> ?grant_type=authorization_code
> &client_id=7_7d67dc7597f034d63775c1d9ae5d9ac7f5750197f
> &client_secret=1sowg0oogc4wg4w4o4gh4va57gggwskkgo08m44ksog8kmu88o
> &code=Q0ODMI2OGYjMjBkN2mJmYzNkOTE4gzMGRhZDZTcykyOGQ3M2M2YTU2ZGVlMzE2MzB2MYkc5NWzE0ZWNiYjI2MA
> &redirect_uri=http%3A//client.example-app.com%2Fauth%2F
>
> HTTP/1.1
> ```
>
> If the request is successful, then a JSON object will be returned by a
>   HTTP 200 code.
>
> ```
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Host: your-shop-name.MYPROVIDER.com
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> Content-Encoding: gzip
> Content-Length: 286
>
> {
>   "access_token": "OGE3MzkxNDlhOGY0M2RjZWM1MWI2MWIxZjRmNDJhZThiOGJkOWZlMWIwNzVkYWFlOWFiMDAxYzkwMDlmMDhlMw",
>   "expires_in": 21600,
>   "token_type": "bearer",
>   "scope": "Your access rights will be shown here.",
>   "refresh_token": "NjczY2E2NzZiNDJjZWI5NTE2YjZhNTlhYTJmOTQ5MjljN2MwNmUxM2MzODc5YTE4OGVjMDdlYTBiMzY1MWI1Mw"
> }
> ```

Comment: Your question doesn't contain much information related to issue. Please add which package you are using, how can we reproduce the error etc

Comment: Without showing us ACCESS_TOKEN_URL and its associated provider documentation, and showing details like GRANT_TYPE, there's little we can do. The diagnostic is clearly telling you to change the type or change another part of the params arg.

Comment: I added the related part from the document @J_H

Comment: Well, http://apidoc.ideasoft.com.tr/ suggests that there's only one valid grant_type parameter ("authorization_code"), and presumably you're providing that. So we must be in the "parameter missing" case, except that you already supplied all of them. So perhaps there's a code defect in the diagnostic message, and it really means "missing or wrong"? If you're confident about id, secret, code, then maybe verify your redirect_uri is indeed properly x-www-form-urlencoded. Failing that, time to contact your provider for support.